# Compare two columns values with regular expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex

I'm trying to compare two columns from two separate tables (Table A, Table B). 
The column in B is equal to the column in table A and it may have extra digits afterwards.

Example:

```
A.Col1 = 95792313

B.Col1 = 9579231300

Which means that B.Col1 = '%' + A.Col +'%'
```

A has around 3 million records and B has 15 million. How can I utilize regular expression in SQL in order to achieve that?

Comment: do you only need it to run once or multiple times?

Comment: Can you join the columns into a temp column? Then use a regex like `^(\d+)[ ]\1` to select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this....

```
declare @a bigint = 95792313
declare @b bigint = 9579231300

select 1 where @a like left(@b,len(@a))
```

I'm just truncating B.Col1, which is @b in this case, to the length of A.Col1 which is @a in this case

So for you, something like

`WHERE A.COL1 LIKE LEFT(B.Col1,LEN(A.Col1))`

Comment: Ah, just see that you posted the same idea earlier... +1 from my side!

Comment: Thank you so much, the solution works but still to slow for the amount of data I have

Comment: @WT86 with 3 million rows nothing is going to be fast since you have to conduct row level comparison on each table.

Comment: @WT86  is columnA a fixed length all the way down?

Comment: @scsimon Neither columns have a fixed length.

Comment: @WT86 then really there isn't a ton you can do that I see. You could insert a column of len() so it's there and doesn't ever have to be calculated again

Answer (score 1):

As your approach to compare these values is not a numerical one, but rather character based, the easiest would be to compare just `A.Col1` with a snippet of the same length cut from the beginning of `B.Col1`.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE(Col1 BIGINT);
DECLARE @tblB TABLE(Col1 BIGINT);

INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES(123),(1234),(12345);
INSERT INTO @tblB VALUES(12300),(12340000),(1345);

SELECT A.Col1
      ,B.Col1
      ,LEN(A.Col1)
      ,CASE WHEN A.Col1=LEFT(B.Col1,LEN(A.Col1)) THEN 'Start with the same digits' ELSE '' END
FROM @tblA AS A
CROSS JOIN @tblB AS B
```

The result

```
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| Col1     | Col1     | (Kein Spaltenname) | (Kein Spaltenname)         |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| 123      | 12300    | 3                  | Start with the same digits |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| 1234     | 12300    | 4                  |                            |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| 12345000 | 12300    | 8                  |                            |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| 123      | 12340000 | 3                  | Start with the same digits |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| 1234     | 12340000 | 4                  | Start with the same digits |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| 12345000 | 12340000 | 8                  |                            |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| 123      | 1345     | 3                  |                            |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| 1234     | 1345     | 4                  |                            |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
| 12345000 | 1345     | 8                  |                            |
+----------+----------+--------------------+----------------------------+
```

### UPDATE

A `CROSS JOIN` with millions of rows in both tables is no good idea. This was just to illustrate the approach. You might use an `INNER JOIN` and put this code as the join's condition:

```
SELECT A.Col1
      ,B.Col1
      ,LEN(A.Col1)
      ,CASE WHEN A.Col1=LEFT(B.Col1,LEN(A.Col1)) THEN 'Start with the same digits' ELSE '' END
FROM @tblA AS A
INNER JOIN @tblB AS B ON A.Col1=LEFT(B.Col1,LEN(A.Col1))
```

Comment: I like what you are proposing, but how can I only print out the matched values only without the non matched ones? The result in my case would be very messy

Comment: @WT86, just add `WHERE A.Col1=LEFT(B.Col1,LEN(A.Col1))` at the end of the query to put a filter on the set.

Comment: @WT86, and be aware, that a `CROSS JOIN` with multi-million rows is no good idea. See my update in a minute!

Comment: Thank you, that is working but it is literally taking for ever 6 hours passed